# Traverse xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml which is of the below format:

```
Xml:
<JobsArray>
<TechJobs>
 <JobsAtSite>
  <SiteJob>
    <JobId>100</JobId>
    <Name>1bc</Name>
  </SiteJob>
  <SiteJob>
    <JobId>101</JobId>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </SiteJob>
  <SiteJob>
    <JobId>102</JobId>
    <Name>xbc</Name>
  </SiteJob>
 </JobsAtSite>
<TechJobSite>
  <JobsAtSite>
   <SiteJob>
    <JobId>200</JobId>
    <Name>1bc</Name>
   </SiteJob>
  </JobsAtSite>
</TechJobSite>
</JobsArray>
```

I want those jobs where the JobId is not equal to 100 for the same  node. So the output should be in the below format:

```
<TechJobs>
 <JobsAtSite>
  <SiteJob>
    <JobId>101</JobId>
    <Name>abc</Name>
  </SiteJob>
  <SiteJob>
    <JobId>102</JobId>
    <Name>xbc</Name>
  </SiteJob>
 </JobsAtSite>
<TechJobSite>
```

This is the workaround which i had, but it is not giving me the expected result.

```
$(xml).find("SiteJob").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find("JobId").text().toLowerCase() !== "100";
}).each(function () {
    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

Any fixes for this. Thanks.

Comment: node name is JobId but you use 'jobID', typo?

Comment: Yes typo, it should be JobId, i will edit that above.

Comment: No, it doesn't, its just a typo here. The code is not giving the expected result.

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rnG9M/, I get only 3 results...

Comment: What kind of filtering do you want? You are now only removing anything that has JobId 100 from the list...

Comment: Yes, which is wrong, i need only JobId 101 and 102 for the same Jobnode of 100. You can see the expected result above. The one that you have shown in the fiddle shows all nodes  except 100.

Comment: Find the `100` node, find the ancestor you want, copy all nodes from there, find the `100` in the copy, remove the `100` copy

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks, can you provide the fiddle. it will be more helpful as i am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(xml).find("SiteJob:contains('100')").filter(function () {
    return true;
}).parent().find("SiteJob").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find("JobId").text().toLowerCase() !== "100";
}).each(function () {
    console.log($(this).find("JobId").text());
});
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rnG9M/1/)